# Get-assignment in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

The (get-assignment) command should return a list of symbols and their true/false value if they are of sort Bool. From my understanding, this can only be done if :produce-assignments is set to true, and when (check-sat) returns sat. However, when I run a small script to test this on Z3, (get-assignment) just returns () - blank.
Here is my script:

```
(set-option :produce-assignments true)
(set-logic QF_UF)
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(assert (= a b )) 
(check-sat)
(get-assignment)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can confirm this behaviour for Z3 [version 4.3.2 - 64 bit - build hashcode 96f4606a7f2d]. Interestingly, putting `(set-option :produce-models true)` into the preamble and placing `(get-value (a b))` after `(check-sat)` yields `((a false)(b false))`, so the assignment seems to be available (see http://rise4fun.com/Z3/zGH7). It looks as if `(get-assignment)` were not supported and as if using it didn't raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of `get-assignment` is not intuitive. It displays the value of `named` subformulas. From the [SMT 2.0 reference](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.0-r12.09.09.pdf) (page 62):

> `get-assignment`
>       is a light-weight and restricted version of get-value that asks for a truth assignment for a selected set of previously entered
>   formulas.(29) Similarly to several other commands already discussed
>   (e.g., get-proof), this command can be issued only if the
>   produce-assignments option, which is false by default, is set to true
>   (see Section 5.1.7 below). Solvers are not required to support this
>   option. Like get-value, it can be issued only following a check- sat
>   command that reports sat or, optionally, also one that reports
>   unknown, without intervening assertion-set commands. The command
>   returns a sequence of all pairs (f b) where b is either true or false
>   and f is the label of a (sub)term of the form (t named f) in the set
>   of all assertions, with t of sort Bool. Similarly to get-value, when
>   the response of the most recent check-sat command was sat, and only
>   then, the set of all assertions is guaranteed to have a model (in the
>   logic) that agrees with the returned truth assignment.

Here is the same example using two named subformulas (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/PR3U)):

```lisp
(set-option :produce-assignments true)
(set-logic QF_UF)
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(assert (! (= (! a :named a_val) b ) :named eq_val)) 
(check-sat)
(get-assignment)
```